# Cached network image is throwing errors after using non-nullable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, non-nullable

Currently using Non Nullable for flutter, all the dependencies work fine except for cached_network_image.

My pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.3
```

In my launch.json for VS code, I've included args:

```
        "--enable-experiment=non-nullable",
        "--no-sound-null-safety",
```

I've also added analysis_options.yaml:

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

The errors I'm getting:

```
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/compat.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/compat.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:5:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/compat.dart' show SqfliteOptions;
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/constant.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/constant.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/utils.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/utils.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/utils/utils.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/utils/utils.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:18:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory_mixin.dart'
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:8:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/database.dart' // ignore: implementation_imports
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:12:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/database_mixin.dart' // ignore: implementation_imports
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:16:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/exception.dart'
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:20:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory.dart' show SqfliteDatabaseFactory;
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:21:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/mixin/constant.dart'
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_import.dart:32:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/mixin/factory.dart'
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sql_builder.dart:1:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite_common/src/sql_builder.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:13:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite/src/compat.dart';
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:16:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'sqlite_api.dart';

../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sql.dart:5:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite/src/sql_builder.dart'
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:12:1: Error: Null safe libraries are not allowed to export declarations from of opt-out libraries.
export 'package:sqflite/sql.dart' show ConflictAlgorithm;
^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:70:17: Error: Optional parameter 'duration' should have a default value because its type 'Duration' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Duration' is from 'dart:core'.
      {Duration duration, void Function() callback}) {
                ^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:70:43: Error: Optional parameter 'callback' should have a default value because its type 'void Function()' doesn't allow null.
      {Duration duration, void Function() callback}) {
                                          ^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:128:10: Error: Optional parameter 'version' should have a default value because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
    {int version,
         ^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:129:27: Error: Optional parameter 'onConfigure' should have a default value because its type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database)' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Database' is from 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart').
    OnDatabaseConfigureFn onConfigure,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:130:24: Error: Optional parameter 'onCreate' should have a default value because its type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database, int)' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Database' is from 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart').
    OnDatabaseCreateFn onCreate,
                       ^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:131:31: Error: Optional parameter 'onUpgrade' should have a default value because its type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database, int, int)' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Database' is from 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart').
    OnDatabaseVersionChangeFn onUpgrade,
                              ^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:132:31: Error: Optional parameter 'onDowngrade' should have a default value because its type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database, int, int)' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Database' is from 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart').
    OnDatabaseVersionChangeFn onDowngrade,
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/sqflite.dart:133:22: Error: Optional parameter 'onOpen' should have a default value because its type 'FutureOr<void> Function(Database)' doesn't allow null.
 - 'Database' is from 'package:sqflite_common/sqlite_api.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/sqlite_api.dart').
    OnDatabaseOpenFn onOpen,
                     ^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/factory_impl.dart:10:24: Error: Field '_databaseFactory' should be initialized because its type 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' doesn't allow null.
 - 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' is from 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/src/factory.dart').
SqfliteDatabaseFactory _databaseFactory;
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/factory_impl.dart:42:30: Error: The value 'null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' because 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' is not nullable.
 - 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' is from 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/src/factory.dart').
    sqfliteDatabaseFactory = null;

../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/factory_impl.dart:53:5: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??=' has type 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' which excludes null.
 - 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' is from 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/src/factory.dart').
    _databaseFactory ??= SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl();
    ^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/factory_impl.dart:67:5: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??=' has type 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' which excludes null.
 - 'SqfliteDatabaseFactory' is from 'package:sqflite_common/src/factory.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite_common-1.0.2+1/lib/src/factory.dart').
    _databaseFactory ??= SqfliteDatabaseFactoryImpl();
    ^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sqflite-1.3.2+1/lib/src/sqflite_impl.dart:17:13: Error: A value of type 'Future<T?>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Future<T>' because 'T?' is nullable and 'T' isn't.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
    channel.invokeMethod<T>(method, arguments);



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/../flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 900

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> Process 'command '/../flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

cached_network_image doesn't seem to have a null safe release. If anyone has encountered this or has insights, please let me know. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: Sadly no, but I think they will have a null safety release soon

Comment: Breaking all previous Dart code sure was a smart move by the Flutter team...

Comment: right... then everybody seems to love this feature. And, now I have to spend 7 more days to fix this LOL

Answer (score 0):

Remove Full Key of 'args':

```
 "args": [
            "--enable-experiment=non-nullable",
            "--no-sound-null-safety",
        ]
```